# Linkedin Video api upload throwing error 500

Tags: php, file-upload, multipartform-data, guzzle, linkedin-api

I am trying to create Video ad Campaigns using LinkedIn API. I am using Laravel, Guzzle and I have followed steps given in documentation to upload video

Initialize Upload for Video
Upload the Video
Finalize Video Upload

On Initialization I receive success response with multiple upload Urls depending on the file size. Using these uploadUrl I am making request to upload the file chunk using Guzzle but in response it is throwing INternal server error 500. I understand it can be server error but not sure if that raised to any header, param or token.

Please help If anyone has faced similar issue and got resolved. I am sharing the response of the initialize upload and request being made using Guzzle.

[Doc Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/videos-api?view=li-lms-2022-11&tabs=curl#initialize-video-upload)

Response of Initialize APi

```
{#1344 // app/Services/LinkedIn/LinkedInCampaignService.php:328
  +"value": {#1324
    +"uploadUrlsExpireAt": 1669664693370
    +"video": "urn:li:video:C4D10AQGwksU16dn3Zw"
    +"uploadInstructions": array:2 [
      0 => {#1325
        +"uploadUrl": "https://www.linkedin.com/dms-uploads/C4D10AQGwksU16dn3Zw/uploadedVideo?sau=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%253D&pn=1&m=91877349&app=4647153&sync=0&v=beta&ut=1cmOzfpLG0Caw1"
        +"lastByte": 4194303
        +"firstByte": 0
      }
      1 => {#1345
        +"uploadUrl": "https://www.linkedin.com/dms-uploads/C4D10AQGwksU16dn3Zw/uploadedVideo?sau=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%253D&pn=2&m=91877349&app=4647153&sync=0&v=beta&ut=3GSFILXAS0Caw1"
        +"lastByte": 5253879
        +"firstByte": 4194304
      }
    ]
    +"uploadToken": ""
  }
}
```

Calling Upload Urls

```
public function uploadChunkedVideo($fileName, $uploadInstructions)
    {
        try {
            $fileHandler = fopen(storage_path('app') . '/' . $fileName, 'r');
            $client    = new Client();
            $uploadPartIds = [];
            foreach ($uploadInstructions as $instruction) {
                $chunkedUpload = $client->put($instruction->uploadUrl, [
                    'headers' => [
                        'Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream',
                        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $this->accessToken,
                        'LinkedIn-Version' => config('services.linkedIn.version'),
                    ],
                    'multipart' => [
                        [
                            'name'     => $fileName,
                            'contents' => fread($fileHandler, $instruction->lastByte - $instruction->firstByte),
                        ]
                    ],
                ]);

                //Push etag
                $uploadPartIds[] = $chunkedUpload->getHeader('ETag')[0];
            }

        } catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ServerException $e) {
            dd($e->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents());
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does the response body actually contain? I would assume there's probably an error message in there.

Comment: Response is Internal server error and return text/html for 500 error linked page. No json response error.

Comment: Why are you using `multipart`? Additionally you are 1 byte short (size = last - first + 1). And you didn't check that `fopen()` succeeds. And you forgot to close the file.

Comment: @Olivier I tried request with content in body and it worked.

Comment: instead of foreach try async would be much faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
 $fileHandler = fopen(storage_path('app') . '/' . $fileName, 'r');
$client    = new Client();
$uploadPartIds = [];
foreach ($uploadInstructions as $instruction) {
    $chunkedUpload = $client->put($instruction->uploadUrl, [
        'headers' => [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream',
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $this->accessToken,
            'LinkedIn-Version' => config('services.linkedIn.version'),
        ],
        'body' => fread($fileHandler, $instruction->lastByte - $instruction->firstByte),
    ]);

    //Push etag
    $uploadPartIds[] = $chunkedUpload->getHeader('ETag')[0];
    info($uploadPartIds);
    
}
return $uploadPartIds;
```